# Delete all installed OEM drivers from FileRepository with .CMD using pnputil.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, drivers

My goal is to create a batch file for Windows Command Prompt that will check for all device drivers that Windows has downloaded from WU or/and that have been installed manually and then delete them from `Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`, all at once.

As far as I understand the batch script should run a loop that will continuously check for the first `Oem*.inf` using the `pnputil.exe -e`, put it into the variable, run `pnputil.exe -d variable` and then start over until `pnputil.exe -e` returns zero result, then quit.

Unfortunately my so called knowledge stops exactly at this point, so I'm asking you for help. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say it.. but this seems to be a bad idea.  It used to be that everything with oemXX.inf was installed by the user and not the operating system.  Now, with windows 10.. I didn't put the majority of these drivers on my system.

Nonetheless, you ask and you shall receive.
It's a little sloppy but it should work.

```bat
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%v in ('pnputil /e ^| findstr /C:"Published name"') do call :line_process "%%v"
goto :EOF


:line_process
Set InputLine=%~1
Set InputLine=%InputLine:~28%

echo.
echo Oem line found: "%InputLine%", removing this package
echo pnputil /delete-driver %InputLine% /uninstall /force

goto :EOF
```

This script ***is currently harmless*** due to an `echo` in front of the `pnputil` command near the end. Until that `echo` is removed, the script should be perfectly safe.

Comment: As I don't value the content of my system volume (it contains only operating system and software, always imaged and can be restored in minutes) I have removed the `echo`... Your script does what I have asked, so THANK YOU VERY MUCH!